# How to pass event change to parent from child component

Tags: reference, components, blazor, blazor-client-side

I tried to follow up "Capture references to elements" to pass change to parent from child component and it didn't work url is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0#capture-references-to-elements

Could please help me with?
a) anything wrong in code?
b) where I could find "Console.WriteLine" info since I could not find it from vs output window.

```
1. ParentComponent.razor

@page "/parentcomponent"
@using BlazorApp.Components

<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<p>ParentYear: @ParentYear</p>

<ChildComponent @ref="ChildComponent1" @bind-Year="ParentYear" />

@code {
    private int ParentYear = 1978;

    ChildComponent ChildComponent1 = new ChildComponent();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ChildComponent1.YearChanged += ChildFiredEvent;
    }

    public void ChildFiredEvent(int _year)
    {
        ParentYear = _year;
        Console.WriteLine(ParentYear.ToString());
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}

2. Childcomponent.razor

<h2>Child Component</h2>

<p>ChildYear: @Year</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeTheYear">Change Year to 1986</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Action<int> YearChanged { get; set; }

    private void ChangeTheYear()
    {
        Year = 1986;
        YearChanged?.Invoke(Year);
    }
}
```

Comment: For what you are trying to do, if you read @chris_sainty blog post  on the subject which can be found here [link](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/) which is the clearest explanation I have found.

Answer (score 1):

In the child component, the YearChanged declaration should look like this:

```
public EventCallBack<int> YearChanged { get; set; }
```

And then you invoke it like this:

```
await YearChanged.InvokeAsync(newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, Samer and David. I believe that I used previous blazor methods. Now it works fine with @ref. Cheers!!! here is code.

```
@page "/parentcomponent"
@using BlazorApp.Components

<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<p>ParentYear: @ParentYear</p>

<ChildComponent @ref="ChildComponent1" @bind-Year="ParentYear" />

@code {
    private int ParentYear = 1978;

    ChildComponent ChildComponent1 = new ChildComponent();
}

<p>ChildYear: @Year</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeTheYear">Change Year to 1986</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<int> YearChanged { get; set; }
    enter code here
    private void ChangeTheYear()
    {
        Year = 1986;
        YearChanged.InvokeAsync(Year);
    }
}
```